# Does using long living access token be counted as daily active users for rate limiting?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Simple question but will affect my coding method so expecting an answer from already running app developers

> Does using long living access token for API calling be triggered as
>   daily active user or should I need to logout and then login user every
>   day to be counted as daily active users ?The reason why I ask whether its shown as daily active users is because it decides API rate limiting

Please read my question carefully if it feels stupid at first,but I believe its really serious one because I don't believe Facebook will implement a factor(daily active users) for rate limiting that can be tricked by a developer if he have long lived access token of the user.

Comment: honestly, if you hit api limits, you are most likely doing something you shouldn´t do. it would be easier to help if we would know the details.

Comment: @luschn forget about not hitting,lets say I will hit api limit.do you have some app running and uses long lived access token ? still shows that much daily active users in app dashboard ?

Comment: it should not matter what access token you use, user token is user token. but why not just test it?

Comment: @luschn yup,I'm testing it.but it takes 3 days to show change in my dashboard.I will post the answer in 3 days.keep tuned

Comment: @luschn.I updated the answer after verifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,using long lived access token is counted as a daily active user.You don't have to worry about logging in and logging out user everyday to be counted as a daily active user.I verified it using a trial approach